# Pass currently focused file to a integrated terminal in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to mimic functionality of Sublime Text where I can create a "build system" that allows user to run some command in terminal followed by path to currently opened file.

Example, I can make some basic script, hit `cmd + b` and see the output in integrated window (screenshot attached).

[image: Build system for JavaScript in Sublime Text]

Is there any way to create a shortcut that will pass for example `node {currentlyFocusedFile}` to integrated Terminal in VSCode?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `tasks.json` that takes `"node"` as the command. Use one of the variables `${file}` or `${relativeFile}` for the arguments in order to pass the current file.

This is a sample **tasks.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        { 
            "taskName": "execNodeWithAbsolutePath",
            "args": ["${file}"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "execNodeWithRelativePath",
            "args": ["${relativeFile}"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Read more about the topic here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 0):

Since the question and answer were posted the ability to send resolved variables to the terminal as part of a command were added to vscode.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_variable-support-in-send-sequence-command

> Variable support in send sequence command
>
> It's now possible to use variables with the
> `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` command, for example:

```
{   
  "key": "ctrl+shift+t",   
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "${file}" }
}
```

So you can do

```
{   
  "key": "ctrl+shift+t",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { 
    "text": "node ${file}"  // or "node ${relativeFile}"
  }
}
```